# Is ok to have one constructor for each built in data types C++

Tags: c++, constructor, built-in-types

Let's say we are going to create a class whose constructor or constructors will save in the variable `words` a very long number:

```
class myClass {
    private:
        unsigned long long int words;

    public:
        ...
}
```

But I want to be able to initialize the class using any built-in type, for example:

```
int a; myClass A(a);
float b; myClass B(b);
long long int c; myClass C(c);
```

Should I implemeting a constructor for each one of the types (listed [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types)) in the form:

```
...
public:
    ...
    myClass(const short int i): 
        words(i) {}

    myClass(const unsigned short int i);
        words(i) {}

    etc...
```

Or should I just implement the constructor for `unsigned long long int`:

```
...
public:
    ...
    myClass(const unsigned long long int i): 
        words(i) {}

    ...
```

What I understand is that using the first option (one for each), this will happen:

```
int a; myClass(a);
// Call constructor myClass(const int i)
// Convert the value i to unsigned long long int and initialize words with it
```

With the second option (one for all):

```
int a; myClass(a);
// Convert i to unsigned long long int and this new value as a parameter for the constructor
// Initialize words with it
```

Now, which one should I use ?. I'm guessing it's just better to use one constructor for `unsigned long long int`.

Is there any scenario where this having a constructor for each one is better?

Comment: *"Is there any scenario where this having a constructor for each one is better?"* Only if they are doing different things. If you are going to convert to `unsigned long long` anyways, you can just as well do that by always taking the target type as an argument.

Comment: Why do you “want to be able to initialize the class using any built-in type”?  Are you writing a “variant” class, or implementing a dynamically-typed language?

Comment: What the tree-with-eyes said. Remember [KISS: "Keep It Simple, Stupid"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason you should make more than one constructor is if extra handling or conversion logic is required. For example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class myClass
{

public:
    unsigned long long int words;// public for ease of example

    // will consume anything convertable to unsigned long long
    myClass(unsigned long long int val) :
            words(val)
    {
    }

    // will consume anything convertable to std::string, and then convert 
    // the string to unsigned long long
    myClass(std::string val) :
            words(std::stoull(val))
    {
    }

};

int main()
{
    std::cout << myClass{ 10 }.words << ": 10" << std::endl;
    std::cout << myClass{ -10 }.words << ": -10 (Two's compliment wrap)" << std::endl;
    std::cout << myClass{ 3.14 }.words << ": 3.14 (Truncated)" << std::endl;
    std::cout << myClass{ "10" }.words << ": \"10\"" << std::endl;
    std::cout << myClass{ "-10" }.words << ": \"-10\" (Two's compliment wrap)" << std::endl;
}
```

10 is converted easily. -10 and 3.14 are converted, but will generate warnings because the value will be damaged by the translation. "10" and "-10" will be accepted by the `string`-parametered constructor, but "-10" will be mangled by `std::stoull`. Additional logic, and probably use of `strtoull`, will be required to handle this, if required.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to implement one constructor for unsigned long long it.

The reason is:
execute below code. Code will not compile due to ambiguity.

Then remove the int constructor and build again. Now the code will compile and execute successfully.

```
#include <iostream>

class myClass {
    private:
        unsigned long long int words;

    public:

    myClass(int i)
    {
        std::cout<<"in Int constructor"<<std::endl;

    }

    myClass(long long int i)
    {

        std::cout<<"in long constructor"<<std::endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
    myClass m(10000000000);    

    return 0;   
}
```